# Expiring URL status questions

Tags: domain, domain-name, url

I'm waiting for a domain name to expire, and the whois lists the expiration date as 11/2/2011 and the lock status as clientDeleteProhibited. Is this a normal part of domain expiration? And when can I expect the domain to be open for purchase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best explanation i've found is [here](http://www.pool.com/help/faq.aspx?lifecyle=1)

So at least 30 days + 1-5 days before it 'drops' and becomes available again.

Comment: there's a really good article explaining how/when domains drop here: http://www.mikeindustries.com/blog/archive/2005/03/how-to-snatch-an-expiring-domain